# How to delete all folders with a specific name using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have got a folder from where I have to delete all the subfolders having name like "tempspecssuite_"

My folder structure is like below

1. Folder1

   - src
   - target
   - tempspecssuite_0
   - tempspecssuite_1

I want recursively delete the folders with name like tempspecssuite_

I tried using below command but it didn't work

```
Get-Childitem -path C:\folder1 -Recurse | where-object {$_.Name -ilike "*tempspecssuite_*"} | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

Comment: You are missing the underscore `$.Name ` should be `$_.Name`

Comment: thanks Itchydon.. there was a typo in my question, but the problem was I didn't remove the Whatif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipeline objects need to be referenced with `$_`, not `$`, as shown below:

```
Get-Childitem -Path C:\folder1 -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -ilike "*tempspecssuite*"} | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

Which can also be referenced with `$PSItem` or set to a custom variable with the [`-PipelineVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.1#pipelinevariable) common parameter. You can find out more in [`about_pipelines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.1),[`about_objects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_objects?view=powershell-7.1#objects-in-pipelines) and [`about_automatic_variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#_).

You could also simplify the above by making use of the `-Filter` parameter from [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1), which also accepts wildcards:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folder1 -Directory -Filter tempspecssuite_* -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -WhatIf
```

Which allows `Get-ChildItem` to filter files while they are getting retrieved, rather than filtering with `Where-Object` afterwards.

You can also limit the filtering with the `-Directory` switch, since we only care about deleting directories.

Comment: Thanks road runner! it is identifying the directories now but it is not deleting the folders. Could there be anything I am missing

Comment: @DevX Are you still using `-WhatIf`? That will only tell you the effect of the command, but not actually delete. Remove this parameter to perform real deletion.